# Spring active profiles setting override

Tags: java, spring

Suppose the spring active profiles are set in the command line, is it possible to override the command line setting via some setting in the application ? I have tried to set it in the application yaml file but it doesn't override and the system is still using the command line setting.

```
//command line
java -Dspring.profiles.active=testing


//application yaml
spring:
 profiles:
  active: dev
```

Answer (score 2):

Spring Boot allows you to externalize your configuration and you can pass in individual properties as command-line arguments with highest [priority](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.0.0-M1/reference/pdf/spring-boot-reference.pdf) .

```
java -jar your-app.jar --spring.profiles.active=testing
```

If you're using maven

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.arguments="--spring.profiles.active=testing"
```

In case of spring boot

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.arguments="--spring.profiles.active=testing"
```